# How to open multiple terminals and execute command in each terminal then save the output from each terminal to a one variable or a file

Tags: python

I have a project that need this code(python language) which opens multiple terminals(linux) then it execute command in each terminal and stores output from each terminal in one file(.txt or any other) or to one variable[list]..

I have tried subprocess with gnome-terminal.The code only opens the terminals execute the commands but closes with status 1 and fails to record the output of each terminal.

```
for item in d:
  sp.getoutput("gnome-terminal -- " + item )
```

where d is the list of the commands.

Comment: Do you really need terminals for this? You can get the output of the command just with `sp.getoutput(item)`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will open three terminals, execute two commands in each terminal, and store the output of all the terminals in one log file. Some important things to note:

1. I added an `exec bash` command at the end of each command string, to keep each terminal open after the commands are complete.
2. I did not include an append flag (`-a`) with the first `tee` command, so that the script will overwrite any existing log files.
3. I used `2>&1` to capture both output and errors in the log, as shown with the second command string.

> **NOTE** - Tested in Ubuntu 20.04, using Python 3.8.

```
import subprocess
import shlex
import time

my_log = "my.log"

commands = (
    # Open a new tab and display time and message
    "gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c \"date 2>&1 | tee " + my_log +
    "; echo foo 2>&1 | tee -a " + my_log + "; exec bash\"",
    # Open a new tab and display time and an error message
    "gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c \"date 2>&1 | tee -a " + my_log +
    "; whatami 2>&1 | tee -a " + my_log + "; exec bash\"",
    # Open a new tab and display time and the current user
    "gnome-terminal --tab -- bash -c \"date 2>&1 | tee -a " + my_log +
    "; whoami 2>&1 | tee -a " + my_log + "; exec bash\"",
    # Display command results from log
    "cat my.log",)

for c in commands:
    subprocess.run(shlex.split(c))
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

**Output:** Three new terminals, and the contents of `my.log` in the initial terminal:

```
Mon 03 Jan 2022 03:16:54 PM EST
foo
Mon 03 Jan 2022 03:16:55 PM EST
bash: whatami: command not found
Mon 03 Jan 2022 03:16:56 PM EST
stack
```

By the way, I am interested in your use case; can you share it with us?